# Calculate the homology of $X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $S^3 = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : \lVert z_1\rVert ^2 + \lVert z_2\rVert^2 = 1 \}$, $D^2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lVert z\rVert \leq 1\}.$  Let $X$ be the quotient of the disjoint union of $D$ and $S^3$ by the smallest equivalence relation identifying $z \in D^2$, $\lVert z\rVert = 1$, with $(z^2, 0) \in S^3$.  Calculate the homology of $X$.

I thought about putting a $CW$-structure on this thing but couldn't find one.

Comment: Well, making $D^2$ a $2$-cell would be a good start. For that to work, you'll need to find a CW structure on $S^3$ with the right $1$-skeleton.

Comment: $S^3$ was my problem.

Comment: I wanted to do a 0-cell, a 1-cell, 2 2-cells, and 1 3 cell.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Friends do not let friends use `||z||` instead of `\lVert z\rVert`!!!

Comment: The spacing you get with two `\vert`s is as bad as with two `|`s. I am assuming norms are wanted, as opposed to absolute values, of course.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Sorry, I was too preoccupied with the quotes in here. I meant to say to use `\|` ...

Comment: @kiwi: Try for $S^3$ *two* $3$-cells, *two* $2$-cells, one $1$-cell, and one $0$-cell. And you should find, as Mariano suggests, that we get the same answer independent of the degree of the map $\partial D^2\to S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to construct a CW structure on your space, really. $X$ is constructed by attaching a $D^2$ to $S^3$ along the map $$D^2\supset S^1\ni z\stackrel\phi\longmapsto(z^2,0)\in S^3.$$ The pair $(X,S^3)$ is a collared pair (see Greenberg+Harper, Chapter 19, for example) It follows easily that the natural map $H_\bullet(D^2,S^1)\to H_\bullet(X,S^3)$ is a an isomorphism. The long exact sequence for homology for the pair $(X,S^3)$ then allows you to compute what you want.

I won't write down the result to let you do it.

Comment: A remarkable consequence of this computation is that it does not depend at all on what the attacing map is (that is, on the specific way the $2$-cell was attached to the $3$-sphere) The result would have been the same if the attaching map were constant, so that the resulting space would have been $S^2\vee S^3$. Can you decide if all the spaces that we get in this way are homotopy equivalent?

Comment: What is a collared pair? (Couldn't find that book online)

Comment: You don't need to know what it is, really. Show that the relative homology of the pair $(X,S^3)$ is the same as that of $(D^2,S^1)$ using excision and the long exact squences of the pairs.

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question, and I'm not interested in this specific result, I am interested in what is a collared pair and why it induces that isomorphism, however...

Comment: In any case, googling for "collared pair" finds many relevant things, among which [these notes](http://users.ictp.trieste.it/~gottsche/algtop.ps.gz) by Lothar Göttsche, which give the needed details.

Comment: @Idan, well, then ask a separate question; it is not a very good idea to ask questions in comments to other questions —it would be useful for you to reference this one, though, of course.

Comment: I just thought you could give me a quick reference. Well, the reference you gave me is a .ps, so you're not making this easy on me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, I gave you two references. And google surely can provide more... The one I linked to was the very first one result, and I did not look further: you can do that :-)

Comment: I love downvotes!